# Neo4j Enterprise Data Migration

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been using **neo4j Enterprise - v3.0.4** ( I haven't bought the Licence yet, planning to do it eventually after going to production ). At the time **neo4j** is installed in one instance and I am trying to migrate the data to another instance with the same environment( For almost a week now ) without success. I've gone through the documentation in which copying the *graph.db* directory to the new **neo4j** data directory should work but strange enough the neo4j service either fails to start or it starts then exits after few seconds.

I tried dumping a cypher query of the old data but still using the command *neo4j-shell* to import doesn't execute even a single line of the cypher query. I've tried most of means to migrate data but I couldn't get it to work.

Could the reason be I am using Enterprise edition without the licence or something else?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise edition doesn't have checks for licenses, that's handled purely by business agreement and trust that businesses will act responsibly.

Here's the [documentation for backups](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/backup/) with enterprise edition for 3.0.x. You may want to double check, when restoring the backup, that the permissions on the restored files are correct (see the permissions on the currently working instance as reference).

Comment: Thank you. File ownership was the problem.